# Function call in another function using same parameter received

Tags: c#, logic

Let's say I have a function call `functA()` and another helper function called as `HelperFunc()`.

```
public void functA(int i, Obj a)
{
   HelperFunc(a);
}

public void HelperFunc(Obj a)
{
    //do something with Obj a
}
```

Can I pass the parameter received by `functA()` to the `HelperFunc()` as above? If so, is it a good practice or is there any other good alternatives?

Comment: yes you can. is it good practice? maybe. cant say without having context.

Comment: Helper functions are usually static. and private to the class (if it only belongs to that class). or static public in another static class (if its mean to be used globally).

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary Why would a helper function be static?  That a function is used exclusively by another function has no bearing on whether it's static or not.  It's static if it needs no instance members, and it's an instance method if it does.  It being private would of course be pretty essential to it just being a helper function; it being public indicates it's useful outside of the context of the other function.

Comment: @Servy I didn't count instance methods as helper functions because they use instance so they are part of the class, not a helper function.. not a function to help :D... but your definition of helper function is professorial so I appreciate that. hmm I change my mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You sure can!

"Good Practice" would depend on the situation and why you are passing it.  Sometimes it is absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this works fine. Yes, this is common practice. We would need better context of the situation to come up with better alternatives.

If it helps your understanding, remember that your "Main" is also just a function, and you can certainly pass parameters from Main into other functions.

Comment: Thank you guys for your feedback!